# Getting a pointer or reference to a member of another object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Hi have an newbie issue with objective-c, cocoa & iPhone. I've declared mapView in my application delegates `applicationDidFinishLaunching:application:` which is instance/pointer of `MKMapView` class. `mapView` is a member of my application delegate.

In my view controller in viewDidLoad: I get instance of my application delegate with the following:

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

My view controller also has got MKMapView *mapView as a member. In viewDidLoad: I try to set it this way:

```
mapView = [appDelegate mapView];
```

but it seems that I'm not able to get pointer or "reference" to the actual mapView because when I try to `[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];` it does not work. How ever `[[appDelegate mapView] setRegion:region animated:YES];` does work.

So the question is how do I get a pointer to `appDelegates` `mapView` from my view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're caching your app delegate's mapView member. However, it's possible that at the time you perform this cache, it's not yet instantiated (setting a breakpoint at this location will reveal that to you).

The answer to your question is: [appDelegate mapView] returns a pointer to the appView member. However, if that member is nil, that's what you'll get back.

Comment: I moved the assignment of `mapView` to `viewWillAppear:animated:` and it is now working perfectly. In addition I made `appDelegate` and `mapView` properties of the view controller as suggested by Matt Long. (didn't try without them thou)

Comment: It definitely sounds like you were loading your view before you were creating your mapView.

Answer (score -1):

You're not retaining the appDelegate. If you created your delegate like this:

```
@property (retain) id appDelegate;
```

Then you have to actually call set on it to retain it:

```
[self setAppDelegate:[[UIAppliation sharedApplication] delegate]];
```

Better yet, use assign in your declaration:

```
@property (assign) id appDelegate;
```

Best regards,

Comment: I can't imagine this is the problem.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Misread the question. Thanks for the down vote though. Yer a sweetheart. ;-)